# React: custom hook doesn't work with context

Tags: reactjs

I created a custom hook to store Objects in a useState hook and allow changing properties without loosing the other entries.

```
const useObject = initialValue => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialValue);

  return [
    state,
    newState => {
      setState({
        ...state,
        ...newState
      });
    }
  ];
};
```

This hook works in my component but doesn't when I assign it to my context.

Here is what I did:

1. I created a context:

`export const navigation = createContext();`

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-glitter-3nob7?file=/src/store.js:40-83

2. I created a useObject variable and assigned it as value to my Context Provider

`<navigation.Provider value={useObject()}>`

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-glitter-3nob7?file=/src/Layout.js:234-284

3. I load the context via useContext and change its value

`const [navigationState, setNavigationState] = useContext(navigation);`

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-glitter-3nob7?file=/src/App.js:476-616

Result:

The context always stores the new entry and removes all existing entries.

Anyone knows why ?

Here is the Sandbox link. You can test it by clicking the filter button. I expected to see `{search:true, icon: 'times'}` as context value. Thx!

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-glitter-3nob7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one important things to note here. `useEffect` in App.js is run once and hence the onClick function set with setNavigationState will use the values from its closure at the point at which it is defined i.e initial render.

Due to this, when you call the function within Header.js from context's the value along with the localState are being reset to the initial value.

**SOLUTION 1:**

One solution here is to use callback approach to state update. For that you need to modify your implementation on useObject a bit to provide the use the capability to use the callback value from setState

```
const useObject = initialValue => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialValue);

  return [
    state,
    newState => {
      if(typeof newState === 'function') {
        setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...newState(prev)}));
      } else {
      setState({
        ...state,
        ...newState
      });
    }
    }
  ];
};
```

and then use it in onContextClick function like

```
const onContextClick = () => {
    setState(prevState => {
      setNavigationState(prev => ({ icon: ICON[prevState.isOpen ? 0 : 1] }));
      return { isOpen: !prevState.isOpen };
    });
  };
```

[Working DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-thunder-hctvj?file=/src/useObject.js)

**SOLUTION 2:**

The other simpler approach to solving the problem is to use `useCallback` for onContextClick and update the navigation state with useEffect, everytime the closure state is updated like

```
 const onContextClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    setNavigationState({ icon: ICON[state.isOpen ? 0 : 1] });
    setState({ isOpen: !state.isOpen });
  }, [state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setNavigationState({
      search: true,
      icon: ICON[0],
      onClick: onContextClick
    });
  }, [onContextClick]);
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-proskuriakova-9monm)

Comment: Thx for the explanation and the demos (: